# Test a controller using Autofixture that takes IOptions<T> as constructor parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Controller class:

```
private readonly DbSettings _docDbSettings;

public CoursesController(IOptions<DbSettings> docDbSettings)
{
    if (docDbSettings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(docDbSettings));
    _docDbSettings = docDbSettings.Value;
}
```

Controller Tests class:

```
public class CoursesControllerTests
{
    private readonly IFixture _fixture;
    private readonly CoursesController _coursesController;
    private readonly DbSettings _docDbSettings;

    public CoursesControllerTests()
    {
        _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFakeItEasyCustomization());

        // Need help here.
        _docDbSettings = _fixture.Create<IOptions<DbSettings>>();       
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions<Infrastructure.DbSettings>' to 'Infrastructure.DbSettings'
```

Any clues!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to assign an object of type `IOptions<DbSettings>` returned by `_fixture.Create<IOptions<DbSettings>>()` to a variable of type `DbSettings` when those types aren't *compatible*.

You can either change the type of `_docDbSettings` to `IOptions<DbSettings>` or create a `DbSettings` object with AutoFixture by saying:

```
_docDbSettings = _fixture.Create<DbSettings>();
```

By the way, it's good to know that AutoFixture can work as an [auto-mocking container](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/03/11/auto-mocking-container/), meaning that you can ask it to create an instance of your `CourseController` and AutoFixture will make sure to provide arguments for all of the constructor dependencies, in this case `IOptions<DbSettings>`:

```
var systemUnderTest = _fixture.Create<CourseController>();
```

You can read more about how to use this pattern with AutoFixture in [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/19/AutoFixtureasanauto-mockingcontainer/) by Mark Seemann.